# I have a struct, but I don't know how to use it

Tags: math

```
typedef struct Complex{
double real;
int img;
} Complex;
```

I've seen people use it as a type like:

```
Complex sqrt( double x) {
}
```

how do 'real' and 'img' play a role in this type of function? Thanks

Comment: What's wrong? It is returning a `Complex` struct by value.

The first code fragment is using Complex either for struct name and variable definition: it can't work.

Comment: Are you missing a `typedef`, by any chance?

Comment: Remember that both structs and typedefs have *separate* namespaces in C. Thus both 'Complex' and 'struct Complex' are valid types with the above definition. Also, the obligatory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number.

Comment: Why is your "img" an int and your "real" a double? Why not both doubles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be used like this:

```
Complex sqrt(double x) {
    Complex c = {0.0, 0.0};
    if ( x>= 0.0 )
       c.real = square_root(x);
    else
       c.img = square_root(-x);
    return c;
}
```

I don't know if it's a mistake, but the Complex::img should be also a double.

(note that Complex numbers is a superset of Reals, so a complex number can be used in the place of a double if its imaginary part is zero)

Answer (score 3):

You might use it like this:

```
Complex sqrt( double x) {
    Complex r;
    r.real = f(x);
    r.img = g(x);
    return r;
}
```

In this example, `f(x)` and `g(x)` would be calls to functions that compute the real and imaginary part of the square root of the complex number `x`. (In reality you would probably calculate the square root inside the `sqrt()` function, but I'm just showing this as an example of how to use the `Complex` structure.)

Here is a [reference that explains structures in C](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/structures.html), which might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

[Complex numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) have a wide range of uses in mathematics - what the role is will depend on the context of the application.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that if the signature is

```
Complex sqrt( double x);
```

Then x represents a real value. So Complex.img could be a 0/1 representing whether x was positive or negative.

Example (taking x as a real number)

```
//C like pseudocode
Complex sqrt(double x){
      Complex result={0,0};
      if (x==0) return result;

      if (x<0){
          result.img =1;
          real = abs(x);
      }  
      result.real= sqrt_(x);//calculates square root of a positive value.
      return result;

}

    //some other place
   double r =-4.0;

   Complex root = sqrt(r);

   //prints "Square root of -4.0 is 2i"
   printf("Square root of %.2f is %.2f%c",r,root.real,(root.img?'i':''));
```

Answer (score 0):

The imaginary part should a be double too.

For a real (double x):

```
Sqrt(x).Real = x >= 0 : Math::Sqrt(x) : 0;
Sqrt(x).Imaginary = x < 0 : Math::Sqrt(x) : 0;
```

Like FinnNk suggested, read a little about complex mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

The square root of a complex number is a calculation not typically found on your hand calculator....

Check out DeMoivre’s Theorem which is used to change variables to polar coordinates - for which there is a closed form formula for the square-root of a complex number, a + ib.

Paul